# Amazon VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-vpc

I am using a netgear FVS336GV2 firewall and I have a comcast business router in front of it. After numerous phone calls with amazon support I have not been able to establish a vpn connection. I am being told that I have to have a public IP address on the firewall. I put our public IP address in the firewall and I was unable to access the internet.

Can somebody please help me configure this this firewall?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the firewall in the DMZ of the router?

Comment: Yes it is in the DMZ.

Comment: Have you contacted Comcast support for help with your internet connection?  This question is unlikely to help any future users.

Comment: Yes I have contacted Comcast. I need help before this question will help other users.